# Leaflet popup options not working

Tags: leaflet, popup

I have some markers bind with popup. I need to give offset for the popup to display on the top of the markers.Now the popup hides the marker. Below is the snapshot of marker and its popup content.[image: Here the popup hides the marker. I need to give some offset so that it is top of the marker.]

Below is my code and this is not working. Stillth popup hides the marker. :

```
 var popup = new L.Popup({ offset:[0,6]}).setContent(contentString);
                      markerdata.bindPopup(popup).addTo(m);
```

could any one help me on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found it more effective to declare the offset when binding the popup (i.e. making it relative to the marker's position):

```
 var popup = new L.Popup().setContent(contentString);
 markerdata.bindPopup(popup, { offset: L.Point(0,16) }).addTo(m);
```

Also '6' is a small offset, which might be enough (depending on the size of your marker), but maybe try a larger one to move the popup enough to make the marker clickable/draggable etc (otherwise the popup gets in the way)